# Colliding with Rigidbodies throwing player object in the air

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a `Rigidbody` attached to my character controller and my enemies. I want the enemies to be able to surround me and have me trapped without me being able to move, so I set the mass property accordingly.

There's just a small problem - if I don't set my mass high enough, the moment the enemies collide with me, my player will go flying into the air. If I don't set my enemies' mass high enough, I will be able to walk right through them. How can I fix this issue? Here is the movement code for the player:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    void Start () {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update () {
        float translation = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * speed;
        float strafe = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * speed;
        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
        strafe *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate (strafe, 0, translation);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("escape")){
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to users here if you included your current movement code, since that's likely an integral part of the solution.

Comment: @Serlite I've edited it to include my keyboard movement script. This script is placed on a capsule collider. The enemies also have a navmesh component attached to it.

Comment: Have you considered using physics methods like `AddForce()` rather than translating directly? The reason why you're getting these massive physics overreactions is because the translation is moving the player into your enemies between physics calculations, creating a big repulsing force. If you instead move your player indirectly using the physics simulation, these problems should disappear.

Comment: @Serlite This is, in fact, what I need to do. Collision is much more accurate and can react to colliders much better with force being applied to the character instead of translating the object.

Comment: @Serlite I've changed the transform.translate to rb.addrelativeforce defining rb to the players rigid body and it works as desired. Can you post your comment as answer so I can give you the proper rep?

Comment: Sure - I've expanded on the comment a bit and added an answer to that effect. Glad to help out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using `Transform.Translate()` to move your player object. As a result, the player is being moved into clipping with your enemy objects in between physics calculations - so when the next physics calculation comes around, there will be a massive repulsing force to correct this. This is what's sending your player flying.

A better alternative is to use [`Rigidbody.AddForce()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) (or one of its variants) to indirectly move your player object. This allows the player object's movement to be taken into account during physics calculations, so it can collide with and be stopped by enemy objects before it starts clipping into them.

If you retrieve and store a reference to the player's `Rigidbody` in a variable, then you can replace `Translate()` with something like:

```
rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(strafe, 0, translation);
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If trying to perform accurate physics (including collision) it's extremely evil to not go through a forces model. It'll never look right, or work particularly well, and you'll wind up with the sorts of behaviors described.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `IsKinematic` is checked. `UseGravity` can be checked or not depend on your situation.

That way, you rigidbody will not be affected by force, collision or joint and is under full control of your script. But maybe they will lose the ability to detect collision as well but I'm not so sure, I haven't tested it yet.

If that was the case, uncheck the `IsKinematic` and instead, check `FreezeRotation` and `FreezePosition` as well. That way, you revoke control of the physics from affecting your position and rotation. You will manually manipulate position & rotation from your script (using CharacterController).

References:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html